# This likely means that the library (@angular/common) which declares CommonModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy

Tags: angular

`
My problem is angular ivy ı couldnt understand my project is work correctly but everywhere is red

[Every module gives same error mesasage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvxyM.png)
[All module is red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PB56L.png)

Should ı upgrade everything but my project is huge ı dont know what should ı do

this is my ng version https://i.stack.imgur.com/wq8Z7.png

Comment: You need to give more information.  Please show us the versions you are using by running `ng version` inside your project.  Also show us what the actual error message is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: this is my ng version https://i.stack.imgur.com/wq8Z7.png

Comment: This likely means that the library (@angular/router) which declares RouterModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy. This is error where ı take every where